# Is there a way to see light frequencies invisible to the human eye without the use of electronic sensors?

Tags: visible-light

I wonder if it's possible to be able to see light frequencies that cannot be normally seen by human eye, without using sensors designed specifically for detecting a certain spectrum range, but rather using some combination of lenses or something else that could transform the light without causing a noticeable latency.

Comment: Well, your typical green laser pointer uses a IR diode laser and a frequency doubler after which you detect the frequency doubled light with the naked eye. Does that count? We report, you decide.

Comment: @dmckee how does the frequency doubler work?

Comment: @zhermes I just used one of the internet's many search engines to find basic information on the subject. I think that's exactly what I'm looking for here.

Comment: Some non-linear optical effect. I think some of our condensed matter people could explain it.

Comment: this may be a bit unfeasible, but if you accelerate the source or put it in a high gravity potential, you could redshift or blueshift the waves into the visible range.

Comment: @Jim. More of those engineering details.

Comment: @Jim seems legit at least for a galactic scale kind of operations. Or expensive beyond public availability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to see the wavelengths beyond the red using non-linear optics: [Second harmonic generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-harmonic_generation).
Basically two photons combine to form a twice more energetic photon.
Green laser works this way.

The opposite of this is the [Spontaneous parametric down-conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_parametric_down-conversion), to see beyond the blue. This involves non-linear optics again. In this process one photon splits into two (entangled) photons.
Efficiency of this process is very low. (But probably usable to see the UV from the Sun.)

A more effective way is using interference of light of different frequencies. The interference can form a third wave whose frequency can be in the visible light range: $\omega_1 - \omega_2 = \omega_3$. This is the principle of the the [optical down conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_downconverter). This way you can shift the visible range towards the higher frequencies.

Anyway electronic sensors remain the easiest ways to see the invisible.

Answer (score 1):

I have built two pairs of [these](http://amasci.com/amateur/irgoggl.html).  They work as advertised, and experimentation with prisms and near-infrared lasers has convinced me that I'm truly seeing near-infrared.

**Edit:**

The linked page gives instructions on making goggles that block out what is traditionally considered 'visible' light (400nm-700nm).  Once you block that, you are left with the near-infrared, which your eyes can see, but with only something like 1/10000 of the sensitivity they have for visible light.  However, on a bright sunny day, even .01% of the ambient light is enough; the final effect is substantially brighter than moonlight, which is about 1/40000 as bright as sunlight.

Comment: Could you include some details about how they work?